# PlatformException (PlatformException(ERROR_GEOCODING_COORDINATES, Service not Available, null))

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation, latitude-longitude

How can I convert location latitude and longitude to a formatted address? I'm trying with geolocator plugin but the line-
**List placemark = await Geolocator().placemarkFromCoordinates(latitude, longitude);** gives me an error with showing platform exception.Please help to solve and thanks in advance.

```
List<Placemark> placemark = await 
Geolocator().placemarkFromCoordinates(latitude, longitude);
myAddress = placemark[0].name.toString();
print("Address: $myAddress");
```

**Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(ERROR_GEOCODING_COORDINATES, Service not Available, null))**
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GccnE.png)

Comment: Are your API key enabled to use google maps? and maybe location services?

Comment: yes, my API key works nicely with google maps

Answer (score 0):

This error seems to be usually caused by network issues or Google Play Services not being present on the device, as mentioned on this [GitHub issue thread](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-geolocator/issues/223). To solve the network issue, you can try using Google's Public DNS following this [guide](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using#change_your_dns_servers_settings).